# Unable to find Xpath element on #shadow-root part of webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I have a website and I want to click on a button which is loaded in by a browser plugin.

When inspect element on web page the plugin section is in a a part called #shadow-open.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Set up Chrome options to connect to an existing session on port 9222
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to the URL of the page
driver.get('https://a.aliexpress.com/_mN5deza')  # Replace with the actual URL

# Find the shadow host element
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'alisave-shadow-host-contentButtons')

# Execute JavaScript to find the shadow root
script_shadow_root = 'return arguments[0].shadowRoot'
shadow_root = driver.execute_script(script_shadow_root, shadow_host)

# Execute JavaScript to find the button inside the shadow root
button_script = 'return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector("#alisave-root-contentButtons > div > div.flex.flex-row.gap-[10px].flex-wrap.flex-1.w-full > button:nth-child(3)");'
button_element = driver.execute_script(button_script, shadow_root)

# Click the button using JavaScript
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button_element)

# Close the browser window
driver.quit()
```

I have tried locating the button with css, xpath and other methods. i have tried debugging the web page to see if python can even detect the plugin generated buttons by HTML ID css selector and xpath however it hasn’t found them.

It is also unable to find the shadow host or root for the xpath.